# How to Encrypted a File and attachment send out in php?

Tags: php

Do anyone know how can I encrypted a file and attachment send out in php?

Example:
If I have a csv file call test.csv. Any way that I can encrypted the file then attached and send it over to someone. Also, how can I decrypt the file from the other side?

Comment: An encryption algorithm.  But seriously: what have you tried?  What specifically is the goal of this?  Your question as it is very vague.  The simplest approach would be to just encrypt the file, attach it like normal, then decrypt it on the other end.

Comment: A typical email receiver is not well set up to decrypt files. The most widely supported method is probably PGP/GPG, but even that is only available to a tiny fraction of email receivers. Password protected ZIP files may be an option, but even those aren't 100% supported. You'll have to clarify your scenario more to get a good answer that'll actually help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the file into $file_str:

```
$file_string = file_get_contents("text.csv");
```

encrypt via [mcrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)

```
$key = "mykey";
$data = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,$file_string,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$key);
```

decrypt in client's end

```
$file_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,$data,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$key);
```

create the file again

```
file_put_contents("text.csv",$file_string);
```